# IOS: problem with alpha

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have this code, where successview start with alpha = 0.00

```
- (void) startAnimation{
    //immediately
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [successView setAlpha:1.00];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //in three seconds
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [successView setAlpha:0.00];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

in this way, in first animation (alpha 0.00 to 1.00), it don't happen in 3 seconds but immediately, instead in the second animation (alpha 1.00 to alpha 0.00) it happens in 3 seconds

if I write only firts animation:

```
- (void) startAnimation{
    //in three seconds
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [successView setAlpha:1.00];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

it happens in 3 seconds, why in the forst example it don't happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS: UIViewImage setAlpha problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997659/ios-uiviewimage-setalpha-problem)

Comment: Don't re-ask the same question, but edit the original to contain the new information you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"successAnimationPart1" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [successView setAlpha:1.00];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And add this animation delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"successAnimationPart1"]) {
        // when first animation is done, call second
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"successAnimationPart2" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [successView setAlpha:0.00];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set animation delay for your 2nd animation (note that using this api is discouraged and you should use block-based `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` animation if you're targeting iOS4.0+):

```
...
[UIView setAnimationDelay:3.0]; 
...
```

But if you just want to change view's alpha to 1 and revert it back you can use just your 1st animation but make it autoreversing:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[successView setAlpha:1.00];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```